# Passing fsolve multiple arguments in R

Tags: r, arguments

I have a function defined in R as follows:

```
fff <- function(Q, Beta1, Beta2, delt, C, r, II, E, vars) {
   A1 = vars[1]
   ph = vars[2]
   B2 = vars[3]
   pl = vars[4]

   f = matrix(0, nrow=4,ncol=1)

   f[1] = -Q*A1*ph^Beta1 + B2*Q*ph^Beta2 + Q*ph/delt -Q*C/r - II
   f[2] = -Beta1*A1*Q*ph^(Beta1-1) + B2*Q*Beta2*ph^(Beta2-1) + Q/delt
   f[3] = -A1*Q*pl^Beta1 + B2*Q*pl^Beta2 + Q*pl/delt -Q*C/r + E
   f[4] = -Beta1*A1*Q*pl^(Beta1-1) + B2*Q*Beta2*pl^(Beta2-1) + Q/delt;

   return(f)
}
```

And would like to solve this using fsolve, but cannot figure out how to pass the various variables and constants to fsolve. I have tried multiple variations of the following:

```
vars0 = c(guessA1, guessPH,  guessB2,  guessPL)
# call fsolve with function, then initial guess, then constants ?
vars = fsolve( fff, vars0, Q, Beta1, Beta2, delt, C, r, II, E)
```

But an error is returned each time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remember to include any required libraries like `pracma` and data for a reproducible example

Comment: What error message? As Hack-R remarked make a reproducible example with all statements and data needed to run your script. Have you read the help for `fsolve`? The argument `vars` should be first in the function argument list of `fff`. So `fff <- function(vars, ........)`.